# Unrelated method of an object is called when creating a pointer to the object

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class called BinaryNode and I want to create a pointer to a specific instance of it. However, in this line of code when I set the pointer the debugger shows that it calls a totally unrelated method called getRight for some reason.

```
template <typename ItemType, typename Keytype>
void BST<ItemType, Keytype>::recAdd(ItemType entry, BinaryNode<ItemType>* subtree)
{
  if (subtree->getEntry() == entry)
  {
    throw(runtime_error("Error: recAdd attempted with a duplicate value.\n"));
  }
  else if (subtree->getEntry() < entry)
  {
    if (subtree->getRight() == nullptr)
    {
      BinaryNode<ItemType>* temp = nullptr; // The pointer in question
      temp = new BinaryNode<ItemType>(entry);
      subtree->setRight(temp);
    }
    else
    {
      recAdd(entry, subtree->getRight());
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if (subtree->getLeft() == nullptr)
    {
      BinaryNode<ItemType>* temp = nullptr;
      temp = new BinaryNode<ItemType>(entry);
      subtree->setLeft(temp);
    }
    else
    {
      recAdd(entry, subtree->getLeft());
    }
  }
}
```

Here is getRight in the BinaryNode implementation file:

```
template<typename T>
BinaryNode<T>* BinaryNode<T>::getRight() const
{
  return(m_right);
}
```

Here is a picture of the debugger

[image: Here is a picture of the debugger]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Makefile:

```
pokedex: main.o Pokemon.o Executive.o Tester.o
    g++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -Wall main.o Pokemon.o Executive.o Tester.o -o pokedex

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -c main.cpp

Pokemon.o: Pokemon.h Pokemon.cpp
    g++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -c Pokemon.cpp

Tester.o: Tester.h Tester.cpp
    g++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -c Tester.cpp

Executive.o: Executive.h Executive.cpp BST.h BST.cpp BinarySearchTreeInterface.h BinaryNode.h BinaryNode.cpp
    g++ -O0 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -c Executive.cpp

clean:
    rm *.o pokedex
```

Comment: Turn off all optimizations and recompile everything. Most debuggers will often get confused with the default compilation options that involve optimizing code, which often moves it around in ways that debuggers can cope with.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik How do I do that? Is that something I type into the command line or do I have to edit the makefile to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not something that works exactly the same way on every operating system with every compiler used in the world today. Since you did not indicate which compiler, which operating system, and you did not show what's currently in your Makefile, I'm not sure how you can expect anyone to be able to tell you exactly what you need to change.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry, my bad. I am running g++ on Linux. I just included the Makefile code in the main post if you could take a look. I did some googling and found out that the -O0 flag supposedly disables optimizations, but it didn't seem to fix anything.

Comment: So, `BinaryNode` has a member function called `getRight()` which is called at `BinaryNode` ctor fired by `temp = new BinaryNode...`

Comment: @Ripi2 the constructor for BinaryNode doesn't call getRight(), so that shouldn't be possible.